# Holomorphic strips versus holomorphic disks

Tags: pseudo-holomorphic-curves

What are the advantages of using holomorphic strips in Lagrangian intersection theory instead of using holomorphic disks?

I understand that for the analysis of strips one often needs to choose particular Sobolev spaces "falling off at $\pm \infty$" in a certain way.  If rephrased for disks, what would be the required behavior for Sobolev spaces at the intersection points of the Lagrangians?